# query list is empty,how to access nested ng-content angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i have three component

**1)** item (html)

```
 <div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
 </div>
```

**2)** list-container (html)

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

list-container(ts)

```
  @ContentChildren(forwardRef(() => Item), { descendants: true }) Items: QueryList<Item>;
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log(this.Items); // issue is here. query List is empty
// how to access items
      }
```

**3)** container (html)

```
<container-list>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</container-list>
```

**in app.html**

```
<container>
    <item *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.name}}</item>
</container>
```